# How to use transaction in sqlite iphone app

Tags: iphone, sqlite

How do I start an transaction in sqlite in my iPhone application. I have a migration file with sql queries and I need them to be executed as one atomical transaction. If something failes I will rollback, but I could need some guidiance on how I do that.

Comment: Have you had a look at the sqlite documentation? In particular, http://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html and http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html

Comment: Yes, but I don't see what I need to write...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start a transaction with: `sqlite3_exec(db, "BEGIN", 0, 0, 0);`

Commit a transaction with: `sqlite3_exec(db, "COMMIT", 0, 0, 0);`

Rollback a transaction with: `sqlite3_exec(db, "ROLLBACK", 0, 0, 0);`

Comment: Yup, though note that there are different types of transactions (EXCLUSIVE, DEFERRED, IMMEDIATE) so you may want to read up on them in the docs. Also, [the fmdb library](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/) is a great way to use sqlite on iOS, as it comes gives you Objective-C type bindings. It also already provides wrappers for transactions.

Comment: @Andreas that is really hard to guess now :P